# Trim White Space with non UTF-8 data

Tags: r, utf-8, whitespace, data-cleaning

I'm trying to clean up some data by removing white space.  But when I run this code, I get the following error:

```
y <- y %>% 
  mutate("Col1" = trimws(`Col2`, which = "both"))%>% 
  mutate("Col2" = trimws(`Col2`, which = "both"))


Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Col2`.
x input string 33 is invalid UTF-8
i Input `Col2` is `trimws(`Col2`, which = "both")`
```

In `col2` I have this value `JOS� SOME NAME`.

I also have this name written as `Jose Some Name`, `JOSESOMENAME`, and some other variations.  I have another file with all of these names in one column and their final cleaned-up version of `Jose Some Name`.  My intention is to join the two files and then only keep the original cleaned up name, but I'm having some trouble matching because of white spaces.

Any suggestions on how to work with this? Is there a better function? The `col2` is a `<chr>` type.

EDIT:  As requested here is the `dput(t)` (which is a subset of y).

```
> dput(t)
structure(list(Col1 = c("Area 1", "Area 2", "Area 3", "Area 4", 
"Area 5", "Area 6"), COl2 = c("BILLY JOE", "SALLY SUE", "LAURA Lane", 
"JOS<c9> SOME NAME", "NORMA NAME", "ESTER BETH")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Col1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), COl2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: What OS are you using? Do you know what encoding was used for your character values? It may be a problem how you are importing the data.

Comment: @akrun, it's a huge amount of data and the consol just shows a bunch of "NA, NA, ...."  Is there something more specific I can tell you?  It's about 1.3 million rows.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a subset of data.

Comment: @MrFlick, I'm on Windows 10.  This is the format I received the data in.  It's special characters in people's names. I believe these are all preserved in the CSV files I have. Looking at the csv files I see characters like, â€“

Comment: @pkpto39 Where did the CSV file some from? You need to know what encoding was used in the CSV file in order to read it in correctly. That's not something you can easily tell from the data itself. Do you know for sure what encoding was used?

Comment: I got this data through a work associate, who has not been responsive, so I'm working on a work around.

Comment: @akrun, dput added.

Comment: With your dput, it is working fine for me ie.. no errors.